# Web certificate issue with Google Chrome and IIS

Tags: php, windows, google-chrome, ssl, iis

I have IIS Web server and two websites on this server. 
1st website with name `first` and IP address is `xxx.xxx.xxx.189` certificate 'first' and is correct.
2nd website with name `second` and IP address is `xxx.xxx.xxx.197` certificate `second` and is correct.

The problem starts since `second` website been added. If both websites are running google chrome returns `Your connection is not private. NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID` on the `first website`. But IE is fine also when I checking certificate information in chrome then chrome telling me that on website `first` i have `second` certificate. IE is correct. I tried to clear cache but it doing the same thing. Interesting when `second` website is off then `first` is OK